# when load file in safari browser, i got ReferenceError: Can't find variable: File API

Tags: safari

i use ngImageCrop when load file in safari browser, i got ReferenceError: Can't find variable: File API. but in other browser my image load successfull.Can anyone give me solution?thanks

**controller.js**

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {

  var file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
  $rootScope.$root.files = file;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(evt) {
    $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
      $scope.myImage = evt.target.result;
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

**index.html**

```
        <div>Select an image file: <input type="file" id="fileInput" /></div>
            <div class="cropArea" >
              <img-crop image="myImage" area-type="rectangle"
                    area-init-size="{ w:cropper.cropWidth,h:cropper.cropHeight}" 
                    area-init-coords="{ x:cropper.areaCoords.x,y:cropper.areaCoords.y}" 
                    area-init-is-relative-to-image="true"
                    aspect-ratio="2.1"
                    result-image-size="{w:1400,h:660}"  cropject="cropper"
                    result-image="myCroppedImage"
                    change-on-fly="true"></img-crop>
            </div>
                <div>Result Image:</div>
                <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}"  style="width:250px;"/></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You did not consider **http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi** or similar? File API seems not to be supported in Safari before version 10.